# Failed to load template: template/typeahead/typeahead.html in Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, typeahead, typeahead.js

I have a running Angular-app in my ruby on rails project and now I want to implement some typeahead search using angular.js and can not find the solution how to make `typeahead directive running`.

Question: How to install angular typeahead directive into my project ?

With present solution described bellow I am getting this console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/template/typeahead/typeahead.html
```

- ng-app is working and related js and css files linked into html as well.

I am following this source: [bootstrap-ui-angularjs](https://github.com/thierryc/bootstrap-ui-angularjs)

What I did already :

1. downloaded `angular-ui-bootstrap.js` into
   `public\assets\javascripts` directory
2. manifested asset pipeline as usually:

   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.tokeninput
   //= require bootstrap
   //= require angular
   //= require angular-ui-bootstrap
   //= require_tree .

3.checked if `js` are on the page:(just scripts in question)

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-ui-bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

```
my ng-app:

    <div ng-app='plunker'>

      <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <pre>Model: {{result | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)">
      </div>

    </div>

<script>

    angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http, limitToFilter) {

        //http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api.htm

        $scope.cities = function(cityName) {
            return $http.jsonp("http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=JSON_CALLBACK &filter=US&q="+cityName).then(function(response){
                return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
            });
        };

    }

</script>
```

Is there something what I am missing in connection to installing existing angular directives? e.g. from [this link](https://github.com/thierryc/bootstrap-ui-angularjs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GitHub code also contains a [folder called template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template), inside which there is a template folder for typeahead. Have you downloaded that and added to your project at the correct location.

[image]

The error seems to be coming due to this typeahead template html file missing. In case it has been added check if location is correct.

Comment: You don't have to manually download and add the file: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/issues/9

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using ui-bootstrap.js, you can use ui-bootstrap-tpls.js. This js file comes with the templates.

To use  ui-bootstrap-tpls.js you have to add js file to your html:

```
<script src="/scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

**AND** in your module you have to add these dependencies:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.typeahead']);
```

If you do these 2 steps you won't get this message anymore:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) _http://localhost:3000/template/typeahead/typeahead.html

What happens often is that people only add the js file and forget to add the dependency to the module.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the templates to your web page if the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file doesn't work or if you want to use the ui-bootstrap.js file:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="isOpen()" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
    <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{match.id}}">
        <div typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html">
    <a tabindex="-1" bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to include the correct .js file which contains the templates.

I replaced "*ui-bootstrap.min.js*" with  "**ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js**"

This fixed it for me. Also see [What is the difference between ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js and ui-bootstrap.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820625/what-is-the-difference-between-ui-bootstrap-tpls-min-js-and-ui-bootstrap-min-js)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. create a new folder `public\template\typeahead`
2. download `typeahead.html` from [this source](https://raw.github.com/thierryc/bootstrap-ui-angularjs/master/template/typeahead/typeahead.html) into directory created in step 1.