# Bootstrap for AngularJS scripts not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, firebase, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularfire

I am using angularFire and ui bootstrap. All of my styling is fine but none of the javascript details are working. I am using a very thick template (tons of plugins and files) so I have tried ordering the position of the script tags in the index.html to no avail. ex: datepicker, range, modal are all not working but I am not getting any errors in the console. This is driving me crazy! here is some code... hopefully it helps.

Index.html bower script calls just before the ending body tag:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/mockfirebase/dist/mockfirebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-payments/lib/angular-payments.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

angular.module calls:

```
angular.module('vagaApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ui.bootstrap',
'angularPayments',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch',
'firebase',
'firebase.utils',
'simpleLogin',
'mm.foundation',
'angularSpinner'
]);
```

example of code not working:

```
<h4>Popup</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Format:</label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does not working mean? Do you see uncompiled angular expressions? Just no data being downloaded? This is extremely vague as to what exactly isn't happening as expected. There are in infinite number of possible causes, so without [an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be pretty tough to help here.

Answer (score 0):

"be sure to include only one file in your project."

from: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ

Could this be your problem? 
Try removing 'ui-bootstrap.min.js'

More about the difference between *tpls.min.js and *min.js here:

[What is the difference between ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js and ui-bootstrap.min.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820625/what-is-the-difference-between-ui-bootstrap-tpls-min-js-and-ui-bootstrap-min-js)