# include ui-bootstrap-tpls.js script

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement an example of [iconPicker](https://github.com/justin-lau/ui-iconpicker) so the files which I should import are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgithub.com/justin-lau/ui-iconpicker/v0.1.4/dist/scripts/ui-iconpicker.min.js"></script>
```

I installed the component with bower

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("bower_components/angular/angular.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("bower_components/ui-iconpicker/dist/scripts/ui-iconpicker.min.js")"></script>
```

the problem is when I try to change the cdn link to local one I can't found this bootstrap-tpls.min.js I found it in angular-bootstrap and it didn't work for me there is any difference?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Install angular bootstrap

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

Ref: [angular ui bootstrap doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#install-with-bower)

Please see this line.

> Note: do not install 'angular-ui-bootstrap'. A separate repository -
>   bootstrap-bower - hosts the compiled javascript file and bower.json In
>   above link.

**angular-ui-bootstrap** : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower

- This repository contains required *ui-bootstrap.js* and *ui-boostrap-tpls.js* files. basically its bower repository to hold Angular UI Bootstrap.
- we get this files from this command `bower install ui-bootstrap`
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file contains **ui-bootstrap.min.js + html templates**.

**angular-bootstrap** : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.

- This is main repository for the angular bootstrap.
- Here you see this line in source `<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>` because this file contains all html + template code which used to show example of bootstrap in angular. So its reuse of `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`.

*I suggest please install bootstrap using `bower install angular-bootstrap`
 and remove `angular-ui-bootstrap` folder*.

**Ref:** Please see this link. It shows the difference clearly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820670/2681997

I hope this will clear your doubt.

Thanks

**Bonus**: Use this to Tool for installing bower dependencies that won't include entire repos in your project.

[bower installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer)

Comment: I've already angular-bootstrap the capture shows this. I asked if there is any difference between all those ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js files cuz I also found one on this link <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js"></script>

Comment: @Rajeun: Means Are you asking the difference between `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js` ?

Comment: exactly why we found the first one in  angular-ui-bootstrap and the second in another component

Comment: @Rajeun: Please accept the answer If this clear your confusion.