# AngularUI modal not showing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

When i click on the button that should open the modal window, the page just blurs like it's going to open but nothing shows. I was thinking if there are problems with the versions i'm loading. I'm loading bootstrap 3.3.7, angularJs 1.7.8 and ui-bootstrap 2.5.0. Does anyone have an idea if that's the case?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: I've personally seen this when the template for the modal doesn't have some of the markup or classes necessary for the modal to be displayed. Try copying a template from the documentation, then go from there.

Comment: +1 to what @sethflowers said. Definitely **do not** use an element with the `modal` class applied. Calling `$uibModal.open()` will generate some containing elements with the proper classes (including `modal`) and having two nested elements with that class will exhibit the exact behavior you describe.

Comment: Do you have the templates included? ```ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js```. For reference see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820625/what-is-the-difference-between-ui-bootstrap-tpls-min-js-and-ui-bootstrap-min-js and especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821567/2619666